# Should I use any() when applying a mask to a pandas dataframe here? And if so, how?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter rows from a dataframe by applying a mask with a bunch of logical statements like so:

```
mask = ( (stock_hist['confirmed'] == True and \
         stock_hist['prevday_confirmed'] == False and \
             stock_hist['nextday_confirmed'] == False \
                 ) \
       or  \
       ( stock_hist['confirmed'] == True and \
        stock_hist['prevday_confirmed'] == True and \
            stock_hist['current_dist'] < stock_hist['prevday_dist'] ) \
           or \
           ( \
            stock_hist['confirmed'] == True and \
            stock_hist['nextday_confirmed'] == True and \
                stock_hist['current_dist'] < stock_hist['nextday_dist'] \
                    ) \
               
or \
    ( stock_hist['confirmed'] == True and \
    stock_hist['nextday_confirmed'] == True and \
        stock_hist['prevday_confirmed'] == True and \
            stock_hist['current_dist'] < stock_hist['nextday_dist'] and \
                stock_hist['current_dist'] < stock_hist['prevday_dist'] \
                    ) \
        )

result = stock_hist[mask]
```

With this, I am getting the dreaded `'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` error message, which has been answered numerous times already.

The thing is, each of the conditions results in either False or True for the row, and I need any of them to be true, for the mask to return 'True' for that row. So I would be happy to throw in a mask.any() or so in there....

However, I am clueless as to how to do that?

Any help is much appreciated!

I expect the result to be like in the spreadsheet below, where the 4 conditional tests and the corresponding end result can be seen in the columns to the right[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of `and` and `or`, you need to use `&` and `|`, respectively. Something like:

```
( (stock_hist['confirmed'] & \
         ~(stock_hist['prevday_confirmed']) & \
             ~(stock_hist['nextday_confirmed'])  \
                 ) \
       |  \
       ( stock_hist['confirmed']...
```

This is because you are working with series and you want corresponding elements to be compared. If you use `and`, all elements are compared as one group which is why it is ambiguous.

Comment: Excellent, in the sense that this eliminated the error. 

However, it also does not give me the result that I want, because the end result is False everywhere, even though instances of the subconditions render to True. 

If I copy the dataframe to Excel and replicate the statement there, it does exactly what I want. I have added the spreadsheet screenshot. The end result now is as if | has the effect of the AND statement, not the OR statement?

Comment: If that is the case, then you need re-check how you have constructed the mask and the conditions themselves. Make sure it follows the following format: `((condition1) & (condition2)) | ((condition3) & (condition4))...`

Comment: Thanks Mohit. 

I would agree that you are right and it SHOULD work. But it doesn't. Maybe i am overlooking a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should use all of your conditions in parentheses as follows

```
mask = ((stock_hist['confirmed'] == True) and \
         (stock_hist['prevday_confirmed'] == False) and \
             (stock_hist['nextday_confirmed'] == False) \
                 ) \
        ...

result = stock_hist[mask]
```

Comment: Thanks Alihan, I tried that even before posting. And it yields the same error. 

So i removed the parentheses again for legibility